# MYSQL Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY RAND

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update with JOIN and RAND

```
UPDATE table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b USING(id) 
SET a.description = CONCAT('different words', b.name)
WHERE a.description LIKE ''
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100;
```

I get the error : Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY

without JOIN the following code works perfectly

```
UPDATE table1 SET description = CONCAT('different words', name) 
WHERE description LIKE ''
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100;
```

thanks for helping

Comment: What do you want to do? what rdbms are you working with?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: description and tags Updated , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `mysql`, you should wrap your query that's working (with the user variable and the order by) as an inline view (MySQL calls it a derived table). Reference that whole view as a row source in the UPDATE statement.  So your query should be something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 a 

INNER JOIN (  
         --query
       ) as someName
 SET a.description = CONCAT('different words', b.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
 UPDATE a
 SET a.description = CONCAT('different words', b.name)
 FROM table1 a 
 INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id 
 WHERE a.description LIKE ''
 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100;
```